# How to return the Comment list by WorkOrder?

Tags: python, django

I have such a case:

I have a WorkOrder class:

```
class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    workorder_num = models.CharField(max_length=64, help_text="workorder number")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, help_text="name")
    content = models.TextField(help_text="content")
```

And I also have a WorkOrderComment class:

```
class WorkOrderComment(models.Model):
    """
    comment 
    """
    workorder = models.ForeignKey(WorkOrder, help_text="belong to which order"  )  
    comment_user = models.OneToOneField(User, help_text="comment user")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=256, help_text="content")
```

So, there is a requirement, I want to list the  workorder comments, so I write the serializers and views:

serializer:

```
class WorkOrderCommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrderComment
        fields = "__all__"
```

view:

```
class WorkOrderCommentListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = WorkOrderCommentSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = WorkOrderComment.objects.filter()
```

But if I list workorder comment, you know it will list all the comments, no organization.

I want to through workorder to get its comments how to do with that?

Comment: You can use the <a href="http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships">nested-relationships</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [nested-relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) to do that.

You do not need the `WorkOrderCommentListAPIView`.

You can in your `WorkOrderCommentSerializer`:

```
class WorkOrderCommentSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    comments = WorkOrderCommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrderComment
        fields = "__all__"
```

Then the access WorkOrderCommentSerializer you can get what you want.